# Header function is redirecting to index.php instead of the specified file (PHP)

Tags: php, html, header

I am currently organising my files into appropriate folders and a problem has arisen. Before changing the code to organise the files everything worked. Now whenever I try to log in, instead of redirecting to 'Staff/staff.php', it redirects to 'Staff/index.php'.

The code is as follow:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include("connectdb.php");

    //if the form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    //get the information out of get or post depending on your form
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        global $db;

        //sanitise the inputs!
        $safe_username = $db->quote($username);

        //run a query to get the user associated with that username
        $query = "select * from user where username = $safe_username";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        $firstrow = $result->fetch(); //get the first row

        if (!empty($firstrow)) {
            //check the passwords, if correct add the session info and redirect
            $hashed_password = md5($password);

            if ($firstrow['password'] == $hashed_password){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $firstrow['userID'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $firstrow['username'];
                $_SESSION['fname'] = $firstrow['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['lname'] = $firstrow['last_name'];
                $_SESSION['staff'] = $firstrow['staff'];

                if($firstrow['staff'] == 1) {
                    header("Location:Staff/staff.php");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    //echo "Success!";
                    header("Location:Customer/customer.php");
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "<h1>Error logging in, password does not match</h1>";
            }
        } else {
            //else display an  error
            echo "<h1>Error logging in, Username not found</h1>";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/theme.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="register-title">Aston Animal Sanctuary</h1>
        <div class="register">
            <!--<form method="link" action="staff.php">
                <input type="submit" value="Staff Login">
            </form>-->
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="register-input" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" class="register-input" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="register-button">
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" /> 
            </form>
            <form method="link" action="register.php">
                <input class="register-button" type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
            </form>
        <div>
        <!--<a href="test1.php" class="button">Test</a>-->
    </body>
</html>

<?php include('View/footer.html'); ?>
```

Is the header the problem?

---

EDIT

The same thing happens with my logout file. It redirects to 'Staff/logout.php' instead of '../logout.php'. It worked before I started organising the files.

The code for logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); //get the previous session info
session_destroy(); //destroy it

header("Location: ../index.php"); //redirect back to the start

?>
```

Comment: Can you post `staff.php`

Comment: In addition to that, do you have any redirects or rewrite-rules in a `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I don't have a .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
header("Location: ./staff/staff.php");
```

and:

```
header("Location: ./customer/customer.php");
```

Comment: Is that the index.php file you have given, if so, in the form, perhaps just leave action blank, as that could possibly be causing it.